# How to write an extension method for a generic type, where one type variable has to be string?

Tags: generics, f#, extension-methods

In particular, I want to write an extension method for this type:

```
type Frame<'TRowKey, string when 'TRowKey : equality> with
  member frame.someMethod =
    // code
```

With that code, I'm getting this error:

> Unexpected identifier in type name. Expected infix operator, quote symbol or other token.

replacing `string` with `String` gives the same result.

The original type is `Frame<'TRowKey, 'TColumnKey (requires equality and equality)>` from the Deedle library.

Comment: Note that the type constraint has to be written on the left side, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Deedle to test this code but you should use .NET extension methods:

```
open System

[<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>]
module Extensions =
    [<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>]
    let someMethod<'TRowKey when 'TRowKey : equality> (frame :Frame<'TRowKey, string>) = // body
```

This is the same way that scrwtp calls 'the idiomatic way' (I don't like to go into discussions about idomaticity) but at the same time it will work from C# as an extension method.

If you want to use it from F# as well as an extension, it has to be declared as a type:

```
[<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>]
type Extensions =
    [<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>]
    static member someMethod<'TRowKey when 'TRowKey : equality> (frame :Frame<'TRowKey, string>) = // body
```

So now you can type `row.` and intellisense will only shows the extension if it its second parameter is a string.

Comment: It probably needs to be a static member on a placeholder type rather than a module let binding.

Comment: @scrwtp yes, if you want to use it also from F# as an extension. I just added the other version.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not even close

Comment: @Gustavo: Yes, I was looking for it to appear as an extension in F#. Makes sense that it's visible from C#, knowing how modules are compiled. Point taken on "idiomatic way" ;)

Answer (score 5):

@Gustavo gave a thorough answer of how to get it working with extension methods. But If you don't have a particularly strong reason for this being an extension method (like C# interop), you might just go with a simple function:

```
type Frame<'row, 'col> = { row: 'row; col: 'col }

module Frame = 
    let restricted (frame: Frame<'row, string>) = frame

Frame.restricted { row = 3; col = "test" } // compiles
Frame.restricted { row = 3; col = 5 }      // doesn't
```

That's what I'd consider a cleaner approach when writing F#-only code - let-bound functions preferable to methods when they don't make sense as an intrinsic part of the type, and less noise from the attributes.